# Star Catalog with radius, luminosity, and spectra class?

Tags: data-analysis, star-catalogues

I am looking for a star catalog (hopefully a .csv file) that contains radius, luminosity, and spectra class data for 1000+ stars.

I have checked catalogs like the HIP, HD, and GAIA catalogs. I have also looked at the VizieR tool. I could not find a catalog with all of these parameters.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Can you mention what you've tried so far? How many star catalogs have you checked and found that they don't meet your criteria? Have you check this site for any that are mentioned here? The more information you give about what you've tried so far, the better that answers can be written to address your specific needs.

Comment: Just type "catalog radius" in the search bar and see what you can find here. *Thanks!*

Comment: I have checked catalogs like the HIP, HD, and GAIA catalogs. I have also looked at the VizieR tool. I could not find a catalog with all of the parameters.

Comment: *Thanks!* I've moved your comment back into your question since some readers will vote on a question without reading comments.